# Apache httpd.conf - route request to different port

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, redirect, httpd.conf

I have a **CentOs 7.1** with Apache `httpd` running on port `9000`.

So if i type in my browser: `http://192.168.56.101:9000/` I see the **Apache Testing 123 Page**.

I also have a **GitLab** Server running on port `8888`, but this port is closed by the firewall.

I want that Apache redirects traffic to `http://192.168.56.101:9000/gitlab` internally to the GitLab server.

I have done this in my Apache config file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
  ProxyPass /gitlab http://192.168.56.101:8888/users/sign_in
  ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://192.168.56.101:8888/users/sign_in
</VirtualHost>
```

When users browse to `http://192.168.56.101:9000/gitlab` the login page appears (css seems broken though), but when logging in this appears:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /users/sign_in was not found on this server.
```

***Is this something that is configurable with Apache and if so how?***

***Do I need to use some sort of Url-Rewriting, if yes which and how to get started?***

Answer (score 0):

All the links in gitlab will presume you are pointing at the original server.

So you need to look at mod_proxy_html to also replace these links in the HTML:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html